# MYSQL Count how many times product viewed in the same session

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a "other people viewed these products" function.

I have a MySQL table which contains all of my page views:

```
Unique ID | Product ID | Session ID 
   1          5           ABCDREA
   2          20          ABCDREA
   3          9           REAVTAS
   4          5           ESAGRRA
   5          20          ESAGRRA
   6          10          MVAOIRAS
   7         6           MVAOIRAS
```

And so on.

I'm trying to populate a table that looks like the following:

```
Product ID | Also Viewed Product ID | Number of Times
    5               20                  2
    20               5                  2 
    10               6                  1
    6                10                 1
```

So what I'm trying to do is first determine in my first table where a session ID appears more than once.
Secondly I'm then trying to then create an "association" between the multiple product ID's that appear in a session.

I'm happy to do this in multiple SQL statements. This will be executed by a perl script, so I can also manipulate data there too.

A good start would simply be able to generate a table that looked like this:

```
 Session   | Viewed Products  
  ABCD        1,52,512,6123
```

I could then work from there.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a column we can indentify the order like a AUTO_INCREMENT or a datetime column with a on update current_timestamp?

Comment: Hi Raymond, yes, there is indeed a timestamp and unique view ID in the first table.

Comment: You should add the data in post.. SQL in a unsorted set of data. Without ORDER BY SQL will not guarantee the same output even when running the same query twice.. So we need those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select
  session_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Product_id) as viewed_products,
  count(*) as count
From
  yourtable
Group by
  session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a test schema like

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `t` (`id`, `pid`, `sid`)
VALUES
    (1,5,'abcdrea'),
    (2,20,'abcdrea'),
    (3,9,'reavtas'),
    (4,5,'esagrra'),
    (5,20,'esagrra'),
    (6,10,'mva'),
    (7,6,'mva');
```

You can get the first one with a simple JOIN:

```
select p1.sid, p1.pid as pid1, p2.pid as pid2
    from t as p1
    join t as p2 on (p1.sid = p2.sid and p1.pid <> p2.pid);

abcdrea 20  5
abcdrea 5   20
esagrra 20  5
esagrra 5   20
mva 6   10
mva 10  6
```

The second table is even easier:

```
select sid, group_concat(pid) from t group by sid;

abcdrea 5,20
esagrra 5,20
mva 10,6
reavtas 9
```

Comment: The first query really needs to have a ORDER BY on some column to generate the same results always. SQL in a unsorted set of data. Without ORDER BY SQL will not guarantee the same output even when running the same query twice..  For the second query the GROUP_CONCAT also might need the ORDER BY option to generate the same results always.

Comment: Sure, if a distinct order is required :)

Comment: "Sure, if a distinct order is required" True

Comment: Thanks! This is looking good. One extra problem, can you tell me how I can ignore any entries where 'productid' is 0? I've tried a WHERE clause and tried p1.pid pid, p1.pid and it just says 'unknown column'.

Comment: Also, I can do this in two queries, but nested statements I'm not so hot on. Do you know how I replace the "session,p1,p2" with p1,p2,count - i.e. a GROUP BY  & Count query - all in one statement?

Comment: Ignore the WHERE question - must have been a typo in my SQL statement. It works fine with p1.pid.